# Changing profile path of windows 11 terminal

Tags: powershell, windows-11, windows-terminal

I'm trying to setup shortcuts (command aliases) in Windows 11 terminal.

When I try to run the command:

```
echo $profile
```

It gives me the path:

```
C:\Users\ashut\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

Now if I try to save aliases to this file, it says file is not digitally signed.

I need to set profile path to:

```
C:\Users\ashut\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

I tried to create new profile but couldn't found an option to set the path. It allowed only startup path to set.

I my previous computer, profile path was not pointing to OneDrive. How to fix this?

Comment: it relates to execution policy. Check [Get-ExecutionPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.2) and [Set-ExecutionPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell's [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) paths are *not* configurable.<sup>[1]</sup>

Since your OneDrive path should be considered a *local* path, the implication is that the effective [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) is `AllSigned`.

If you don't want to sign your profile file, use a less restrictive execution policy; a good compromise is `RemoteSigned` (only scripts downloaded from the web then require a signature).

```bash
# Open a *new* PowerShell session afterwards.
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Force -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned
```

Note:

- Scoping the change to the current user obviates the need to run from an *elevated* (admin) session, but obviously only takes effect for the *current* user.
- If execution policies are set *via GPOs* (Group Policy Objects) in your organization, you will *not* be able to make this change.

---

<sup>[1] If you want a file at `C:\Users\ashut\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` to *also* exist, you can define it as a *symbolic link* that points to `C:\Users\ashut\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`.</sup>